# golang http too many files

Tags: http, go

In my project, I need send http requests 5000 times/s. I did read some blogs and questions about the problem, and I try things:

1. change process ulimit to 10^5
2. close `content.Body`
3. use one http client and reuse connection

But they just don't work. Indeed, my app can run for several minutes or hours, then it reach to the ulimit value in my settings(first 50000, late 100000, use shell cmd `ls -l /proc/PID/fd | wc -l`). The http request is as follows:

```
package http

import "downloader/request"
import "downloader/response"
import "downloader/proxy"
import "downloader/ssdb"
import "net/http"
import "net/url"
import "time"
import "fmt"
import "strings"
import "io/ioutil"
import "errors"

func getProxy(ssdbClients []*ssdb.SSDBClient, proxyName string, reqUrl string) (string, error){
    var err error
    p := ""
    url := ""
    if proxyName != "" {
        p, err = proxy.GetOne(ssdbClients,proxyName)
        if err != nil {
            return url, err
        }
        if strings.HasPrefix(reqUrl, "https") {
            url = fmt.Sprintf("https://%s", p)
        } else if strings.HasPrefix(reqUrl, "http") {
            url = fmt.Sprintf("http://%s", p)
        } else {
            return url,errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("reqUrl %s not valid", reqUrl))
        }
        return url, err
    }
    return url, err
}

func customProxy(req *http.Request) (*url.URL, error) {
    httpProxy := req.Header.Get("HttpProxy")
    if httpProxy == "" {
        return nil, nil
    } else {
        return url.Parse(httpProxy)
    }
}

func GetClient() *http.Client {
    var client http.Client
    client = http.Client{
        Timeout: 15 * time.Second,
    }
    transport :=  http.Transport{
        Proxy: customProxy,
        DisableCompression: false,
        MaxIdleConnsPerHost: 10000,
    }
    client.Transport = &transport
    return &client
}

func structResponse(req *request.HttpRequest, content *http.Response, proxy string) (response.HttpResponse, error) {
    var resp response.HttpResponse
    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(content.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return resp, err
    }
    header := make(map[string]interface{})
    for k, v := range content.Header {
        if len(v) > 0 {
            header[k] = v[0]
        }
    }
    var encoding string
    encoding = content.Header.Get("Content-Encoding")
    resp = response.HttpResponse {
        Request: *req,
        ErrorCode: 0,
        ErrorMsg: "",
        StatusCode: content.StatusCode,
        Reason: content.Status,
        Html: string(data),
        Headers: header,
        Encoding: encoding,
        Url: req.Url,
        CrawlerName: req.CrawlerName,
        ProxyName: req.ProxyName,
        HttpProxy: proxy,
    }
    return resp, err
}

func Send(ssdbClients []*ssdb.SSDBClient, r *request.HttpRequest, httpClient *http.Client) (response.HttpResponse, error) {
    var resp response.HttpResponse
    var err error
    var httpProxy string

    httpProxy, err = getProxy(ssdbClients, r.ProxyName, r.Url)
    if err != nil {
        return resp, err
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest(r.Method, r.Url, strings.NewReader(r.Data))
    if err != nil {
        return resp, err
    }

    u, err := url.Parse(r.Url)
    if err != nil {
        return resp, err
    }

    defaultHeaders := map[string] string {
        "User-Agent": `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) 
        AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36`,
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language": "zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en;q=0.6",
        "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
        "Host": u.Host,
        "HttpProxy": httpProxy,
    }

    for k, v := range defaultHeaders {
        req.Header.Set(k, v)
    }

    for k, v := range r.Headers {
        req.Header.Set(k, fmt.Sprintf("%v", v))
    }

    for k, v := range r.Cookies {
        req.Header.Set("Cookie", fmt.Sprintf("%s=%v", k, v))
    }


    values := req.URL.Query()
    for k, v := range r.Params {
        values.Add(k, fmt.Sprintf("%v", v))
    }
    req.URL.RawQuery = values.Encode()

    content, err := httpClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return resp, err
    }
    defer content.Body.Close()
    resp, err = structResponse(r, content, httpProxy)
    if err != nil {
        return resp, err
    }
    respCookies := make(map[string] interface{})
    if httpClient.Jar != nil {
        cookies := httpClient.Jar.Cookies(req.URL)
        for _, cookie := range cookies {
            respCookies[cookie.Name] = cookie.Value
        }
        resp.Cookies = respCookies
    }
    return resp, err
}
```

And I use my http library as follows:

```
func sendRequest(clients []*ssdb.SSDBClient, r *request.HttpRequest, httpClient *http.Client) {
    for {
        resp, err := http.Send(clients, *r, httpClient)
        if err != nil {
            utils.Error.Println("http send fail ", err.Error())
        } else {
            if resp.StatusCode == 200 {
                utils.Info.Println("status 200, success")
            } else {
                utils.Warning.Println("status ", resp.StatusCode, resp.Reason)
            }
        }
    }
}
func main() {
    httpClient := http.GetClient()
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    for i:=0;i<crawlerConsumers;i++ {
        go sendRequest(clients, r, httpClient)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Can anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

- Adding proxy have effects on http client connections?
- Do my app have to reach the ulimit value because my app send requests
  5000 times per second and one request have 15 seconds timeout?
- Do I close all the file handles?
- Do I forget to handle some exceptions?

Add Some profile info with pprof

```
/debug/pprof/

profiles:
0   block
99490   goroutine(This number is growing constantly, very strange)
1640    heap
14  threadcreate

# runtime.MemStats
# Alloc = 210967776
# TotalAlloc = 3673382376
# Sys = 646805032
# Lookups = 29226
# Mallocs = 15590422
# Frees = 14236863
# HeapAlloc = 210967776
# HeapSys = 331415552
# HeapIdle = 72081408
# HeapInuse = 259334144
# HeapReleased = 0
# HeapObjects = 1353559
# Stack = 283049984 / 283049984
# MSpan = 4007136 / 4112384
# MCache = 9664 / 16384
# BuckHashSys = 1575958
# NextGC = 306292818
# PauseNs = [2096153 2554867 2962532 4711468 3373778 3548443 1764893 1961992 2434108 2658626 2627832 2564733 2610212 3278169 2954882 2847604 4443650 3582780 3557718 4201288 4762243 8349689 3812924 5098353 5196422 4494087 5209715 5978150 5060982 4825367 6529020 5738726 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
# NumGC = 32
# EnableGC = true
# DebugGC = false


# runtime.MemStats
# Alloc = 334390488
# TotalAlloc = 7408124464
# Sys = 963748912
# Lookups = 64289
# Mallocs = 31759565
# Frees = 29798637
# HeapAlloc = 334390488
# HeapSys = 536903680
# HeapIdle = 171114496
# HeapInuse = 365789184
# HeapReleased = 0
# HeapObjects = 1960928
# Stack = 381648896 / 381648896
# MSpan = 4958240 / 5160960
# MCache = 9664 / 16384
# BuckHashSys = 1625694
# NextGC = 337299393
# PauseNs = [2096153 2554867 2962532 4711468 3373778 3548443 1764893 1961992 2434108 2658626 2627832 2564733 2610212 3278169 2954882 2847604 4443650 3582780 3557718 4201288 4762243 8349689 3812924 5098353 5196422 4494087 5209715 5978150 5060982 4825367 6529020 5738726 5563959 6997601 6906020 6778559 7592484 7193865 7198439 7815078 7217336 6923856 7127406 7491410 7029097 7757883 6861948 7295746 7245947 9037505 7656431 7322897 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
# NumGC = 52
# EnableGC = true
# DebugGC = false

# runtime.MemStats
# Alloc = 468642296
# TotalAlloc = 25479911160
# Sys = 1185490448
# Lookups = 278984
# Mallocs = 119997794
# Frees = 117189156
# HeapAlloc = 468642296
# HeapSys = 680919040
# HeapIdle = 174424064
# HeapInuse = 506494976
# HeapReleased = 0
# HeapObjects = 2808638
# Stack = 448397312 / 448397312
# MSpan = 6943104 / 7061504
# MCache = 9664 / 16384
# BuckHashSys = 1757422
# NextGC = 485127068
# PauseNs = [2096153 2554867 2962532 4711468 3373778 3548443 1764893 1961992 2434108 2658626 2627832 2564733 2610212 3278169 2954882 2847604 4443650 3582780 3557718 4201288 4762243 8349689 3812924 5098353 5196422 4494087 5209715 5978150 5060982 4825367 6529020 5738726 5563959 6997601 6906020 6778559 7592484 7193865 7198439 7815078 7217336 6923856 7127406 7491410 7029097 7757883 6861948 7295746 7245947 9037505 7656431 7322897 7155298 7288230 8027051 7442561 7528532 8418744 7847097 8791562 7242055 8418159 7677703 8662475 8408315 8562446 8110168 7308570 8593523 7820707 8734530 8981041 8721316 8152324 8390552 8603397 9059668 8153933 7986519 7744819 8491656 8562181 7816543 9145512 7902742 7780778 7636659 13573779 12684501 94808535 9443609 8257986 9072718 9634563 9229626 9449536 8644605 8898286 8499036 13101964 8743251 9119720 9267487 8178551 8444107 8362330 8447271 8558115 8788773 9977627 9058283 8743149 8508649 9099904 9382220 9684119 9789404 9730475 8506223 10363233 9979499 9033233 9634088 9739395 9129433 9122154 8615491 9632523 9314836 9845890 9888849 10034358 10207887 10073912 9892683 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
# NumGC = 135
# EnableGC = true
# DebugGC = false
```

Add cpu profile .svg file [attachment](https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0BzYJEkEc-oEtTXZ1UHhDblBqSWM&export=download)

Finally, I figure it out that I should add timeout to the http client as follows:

```
transport :=  http.Transport{
    Proxy: customProxy,
    DisableCompression: false,
    MaxIdleConnsPerHost: 10000,
    Dial: (&net.Dialer{
                Timeout:   15 * time.Second,
                KeepAlive: 15 * time.Second,
            }).Dial,
    TLSHandshakeTimeout: 5 * time.Second,
}
```

Comment: You want to use pprof to find leaks, the symptoms are definitely indicative of leaks.

Comment: Is the 5000req/sec to a single host, or many?

Comment: @GarMan: I'm not sure how you intend to use pprof to show where a file descriptor wasn't closed, but a sampled memory or cpu profile is generally not useful in this case.

Comment: @Cphilo: You ask about the proxy, but does using the proxy change the behavior you see? (it could have an effect, but I'm not sure what your actual problem is yet)

Comment: @JimB using the inuse_objects pprof heap profiler, and then rerunning it some time later using the `-base` argument you can compare memory at different points. A leak is very clear to see in almost every example I have tried this with.

Comment: @GarMan: OK good point, but it still doesn't show where the cleanup is being missed (and in the case of FDs, lsof or a stacktrace usually shows the same info; but maybe I just have too much practice at reading those).

Comment: @JimB, to a single host using http proxy

Comment: @GarMan, I will try using pprof to debug this problem

Comment: @JimB, `crawlerConsumers` is 5000. And `MaxIdleConnsPerHost` is greater than `crawlerConsumers`.

Comment: SendRequest function has an infinite for loop. Is this intentional?

Comment: @Cphilo: sorry, missed that in the example. Have you confirmed all the FDs are taken by http connections to the host or proxy (does this ssdb do anything over the network, or are any files involved?)? Also, are you sure that 5000 concurrent connections is efficient? Fewer connections in parallel may make better use of IO and CPU.

Comment: @JimB: Yes, ssdb client use redis connection pool, I've check this connection numbers. What do you mean fewer connections in parallel?

Comment: @Mark: yes, It is intentional.

Comment: @Cphilo: I mean why is `crawlerConsumers` 5000? Making 5000 requests in parallel isn't usually faster (though if you've tested this, and the connections are slow enough, that's fine). My hunch is that the contention on the idle connection pool from having so many consumers is preventing connections from being recycled fast enough, which would cause surges in the number of open connections. Maybe try fewer consumers and/or multiple http client+transports.

Comment: @JimB, I take your advice. `crawlerConsumers` 5000, 500 `crawlerConsumers` per http client, total 10 http client. Yeah, network utilization seems to be improved. But it did not solve this problem. Goroutines continue growing and the process file handles continue growing into the ulimit value.  In the cpu profile attachment, https request seems cost much time, any ideas about https request? Or should I improve ulimit value?

Comment: @Cphilo: are you on a very old version of go? Those timeouts should have been set by default (though slightly longer).

Comment: @JimB, go version go1.5.1 linux/amd64. Indeed, `DefaultTransport` have default `TLSHandshakeTimeout ` value (https://golang.org/src/net/http/transport.go). But I use my own `Transport` and I did not set the`TLSHandshakeTimeout` value.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at this yet:
http://craigwickesser.com/2015/01/golang-http-to-many-open-files/

basically he suggests using `req.Header.Set("Connection", "close")`

I wonder if you're connections are staying open until the timeout/keepalive is hit, so manually setting it to less than the default is closing the connection fast enough where you don't overflow?

Comment: https://oroboro.com/file-handle-leaks-server/ that kind of explains the ways you might be able to get that error